# Error al iniciar el contenedor docker-compose -> quiero iniciar un demo de mi odoo

Tags: docker-compose

estoy tratando de ejecutar mi docker-compose pero me arroja el siguiente error

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/z/ResUlt/Respaldo/Docker/odoo/odoo15-prod/odoo/odoo.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/odoo/odoo.conf": mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/z/ResUlt/Respaldo/Docker/odoo/odoo15-prod/odoo/odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf (via /proc/self/fd/14), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type..

este es mi docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    postgresql:
        image: postgres:12
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ./postgresql/.env.dev
        volumes: 
            - postgresql_odoo15_prod-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    odoo:
        build: ./odoo
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgresql
        volumes: 
            - odoo15_prod-data:/var/lib/odoo/
            - ./odoo/extra-addons/:/mnt/extra-addons/
            - ./odoo/enterprise/:/mnt/enterprise/
            - ./odoo/odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
            
        ports:
            - 8070:8069
        env_file:
            - ./odoo/.env.dev
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/ssl/nginx/
            - ./nginx/sites-enabled/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        links:
            - odoo
        #depends_on:
        #    - odoo14
volumes: 
    postgresql_odoo15_prod-data:
    odoo15_prod-data:
```

Comment: `./odoo/odoo.conf` no es un directorio que puedas montar como volumen, de ahí el error